# EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node

Tags: entities

I'm doing a drupal 7 website, I've now started to experience a "EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7820 of C:\xampp----\includes\common.inc)." error whn I try to view a node in full view mode and only if I'm logged in as administrator.

This is happening here:

```
if (!empty($info['entity keys']['bundle'])) {
// Explicitly fail for malformed entities missing the bundle property.
if (!isset($entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']}) || $entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']} === '') {
  var_dump($entity);
  throw new EntityMalformedException(t('Missing bundle property on entity of type @entity_type.', array('@entity_type' => $entity_type)));
}
```

I found some pages about this error but none seems to apply to my case. I put a var_dump just before the instruction throwing the exception and all I get is bool(false). I've checked all the bool fields of the node and they all have #bundle correctly set.

I think the problem might have started after installing the database optimization module. I found some information regardin this error and clearing the form_cache but I didn't understand if this can apply to my case.

I guess these hints are enough to trace the problem for a drupal expert, unfortunately not for me.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the `var_dump` or `dpm()` output the node object? It should contain the `$node->type` property.

Comment: var_dump($entity) returns just (bool)false. I checked also the node with devel and the type property is correctly set to 'my_job_type'

Comment: I've tried solutions proposed in other pages like installing and running the taxonomy orphanage module, or running queries to find orphaned nodes but I didn't find anything so far.

Comment: The issue should be that there is no node object at all rather than the $node->type field in particular is missing.

Comment: I have only one node of this type. I can view it as anonymous or logged in user, I get the error only when I try to view it as administrator. I'm trying to disable the radioactivity module but drupal doesn't let me do it. it says there a re still fields in use, which is not true, I've deleted all nodes and removed the field from content type. May me this is anothr hint.

Comment: Are you trying to get the node ID from URL arguments (`arg()`) and load the node? Because it wouldn't work in ajax. I can't figure out any other reason without the seeing the code that leads to this error.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ayeshk, unfortunately that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

It was this:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1888610
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.